# Code jumps to unknown class while executing method in backing bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces

I have a problem where I call a method in the backing bean which is supposed to update a list after which a rich:datagrid is rerender on my xhtml page to reflect the changes.Via debugging I can confirm that the method is called succesfully however it jumps out of the method after one iteration throught the list and goes to a different class(not one of my classes).It never returns to the method and the datagrid is also never rerendered.

Below is the relevant html and java code.
HTML:

```html
<table width="650px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="325px" align="left"><h:outputText style="white-space: pre; font-weight: normal; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px">Name :</h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="searchName" size="25" value="#{myBean.searchName}"></h:inputText></td>
            <td width="325px" align="left"><h:outputText style="white-space: pre; font-weight: normal; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px">Surname :</h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="searchSurname" size="25" value="#{myBean.searchSurname}"></h:inputText></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="325px" align="left"><h:outputText style="white-space: pre; font-weight: normal; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px">ID :</h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="searchId" size="25" value="#{myBean.searchId}"></h:inputText></td>
            <td width="325px" align="left"><h:outputText style="white-space: pre; font-weight: normal; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px">Status :</h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="searchStatus" size="25" value="#{myBean.searchStatus}"></h:inputText></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><a4j:commandButton action="#{myBean.searchRecords}" value="Search" render="dataList"></a4j:commandButton></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Java:

```java
public void searchRecords(){
    if(dataList == null){
        dataList = searchList;
    }

    searchList = Collections.<ListObj>emptyList();

    for (ListObj obj : dataList) {
        if((obj.getName().contains(searchName)) | (obj.getSurname().contains(searchSurname)) | (obj.getIdNumber().contains(searchId)) | (obj.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(searchStatus))){
            searchList.add(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The code jumps to the unkown class on searchList.add(obj).I am using Apache MyFaces JSF 2.1, RichFace 4.3 and Java 1.6. I think this might have something to do with the JSF lifecycle as my understanding of the lifecycle is severly lacking,but I could be wrong about that for the same reason.I am in the process of reading a post by BalusC about the lifecycle though.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the name of unknown class and method that your debugger shows to be executing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source cause is that you are trying to add elements to empty list. Method `Collections.emptyList();` returns instance of special inner class `EmptyList` defined into class `Collections`. This special list cannot be modified. Attempt to add elements to it   will not modify its content.

So, change line `searchList = Collections.<ListObj>emptyList();` to `searchList = Collections.new ArrayList<ListObj>();` and try again.

Comment: Thx alot for this answer.I had no idea it doesn't just return a list of ListObj that is empty.